# FireBase and iOS: Unable to return variable within block despite I use the __block identifier

Tags: ios, objective-c, asynchronous, firebase, block

When I run the following code :

```
(int) function{
__block int count = 0;

[[[_ref child:@“lambda”] child:serial] observeEventType:FIRDataEventTypeValue withBlock:^(FIRDataSnapshot * _Nonnull snapshot) {
    // Get user value
    count++;

    NSLog(@“Inside: %i", count);
} withCancelBlock:^(NSError * _Nonnull error) {
}];;

NSLog(@“Outside: %i", count);
return count; 
}
```

I get the following output:

> Inside: 1 
>   Outside: 0

And if I call it as a function **the function returns 0 and not 1**.

- I am using the **__block identifier** but despite that the variable does not seem to stay modified. Why?
- **How can I get the function to return 1 when the Inside value is 1?**

Comment: You are confused about asynchronous and synchronous code execution.  That block is executed *some time later* while the outside `NSLog()` is executed immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Output is proper. if you debug this code, first wit will execute `NSLog(@“Outside: %i", count);`(so this will print 0) and then `NSLog(@“Inside: %i", count);` (so this will print 1).

Updated answer for updated Question :

With the inside value of count you want to perform execution of some code. So pass that code as block to the function argument. 
Code will be something like below :

```
-(void) functionwithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(void)completionHandler : {
   _block int count = 0;

 [[[_ref child:@“lambda”] child:serial] observeEventType:FIRDataEventTypeValue withBlock:^(FIRDataSnapshot * _Nonnull snapshot) {
// Get user value
count++;
 completionHandler ();
NSLog(@“Inside: %i", count);
} withCancelBlock:^(NSError * _Nonnull error) {
}];;


}
```

Refer below link for more info about block:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithBlocks/WorkingwithBlocks.html

Comment: Thanks, I have added some additional details. Would you be able to double check them?

Comment: This answer doesn't explain *why* the inside `NSLog()` is called after the outside one.